# Max/min help please

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

I am studying analysis, and we're just getting to the topic of maxima and minima. I'm trying to find the maximum and minimum of the set $$S := (0,4] \cap \Bbb{Q}.$$ I know the minimum DNE, and I know why it doesn’t exist. But I don’t know why the maximum is $4$ and not $> 4,$ if the universal set extends past $4$? Any help would be appreciated. Please and thank you.

Comment: Please, always start by stating the problem clearly.

Comment: Will do. I’m new at this.

Comment: Is Q the set of rational numbers?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: $S = (0,4] \cap \mathbb Q = \{ x \in (0,4] \mid x \text{ is rational}\}$. I think it should be clear that $\max S = 4$. What is the problem?

Comment: The maximum of a set is an element of the set, isn't it? If $x>4,$ is $x\in (0,4]?$

Comment: That x isn't in the interval , since you take only the rationals that are equal or smaller then 4 and bigger then 0.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. My apologies again.

Comment: Thanks Ron and everyone else

Answer (score 0):

$\max S = 4$ since $4 \in (0, 4]$ and $4 \in \mathbb{Q}$ imply $4 \in S$, and there is no $x \in S$ for which $x > 4$.

$\min S$ does not exist. Suppose $\min S = x$. Then $y = x/2 < x$ and $y \in S$, a contradiction.